# How to completely clean the element?

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I use [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

I need clear element `$e` `<font size="2"><b>Listen to INT_routine on the January 15th, 2007 Urban-D Radio Podcast!</b></font>`

I use function: `$e->clear()` element deletes, but leaves `</font>`

how to completely clean the element?

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e never used this library, but looking through it. See if this does the trick ..

```
echo str_get_html('<font size="2"><b>Listen to INT_routine on the January 15th, 2007 Urban-D Radio Podcast!</b></font>')->plaintext;
```

or this . .

```
$tagtext = (string)"<font size="2"><b>Listen to INT_routine on the January 15th, 2007 Urban-D Radio Podcast!</b></font>";
var_dump(str_get_html($tagtext)->plaintext);
```

**Edit:**

```
// Example 

$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");  
$e = $html->find("div", 0); 

echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div" 

echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>" 

echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"

echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
```

Comment: end? this get me plaintext. but to me it should be removed, tagged and everything.

Comment: scushi paruski . . ya nea panimya shtu ti guriesh.

Comment: plaintext - prosto vernet mne tekst, a mne nuzhno udalitʹ vesʹ tag

Comment: hmm, eta nea rabatuit? `echo str_get_html('<font size="2"><b>Listen to INT_routine on the January 15th, 2007 Urban-D Radio Podcast!</b></font>')->plaintext` or `var_dump(str_get_html('<font size="2"><b>Listen to INT_routine on the January 15th, 2007 Urban-D Radio Podcast!</b></font>')->plaintext)`